# Distance function for DBSCAN

Tags: machine-learning, cluster-analysis, unsupervised-learning

I will like to use a clustering algorithm to find a clustering for a big Digraph, and I will like remove noise from this graph too. So, I was thinking to use the **DBSCAN** approach, because I saw that we can give to the algorithm a distance function for determining the *distance/similarity* between two different nodes.

My question is, how can I define a distance function which **increases** the similarity between two nodes closes in terms of hops and **decrease** when a node is isolated.

I don't have coordinates or node attributes, so I can not use those. I only have the topology of the graph.

The expected output will be something like this:

[image]

I'm really concern about the complexity of the solution. How can approximate a clustering with a linear complexity ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is wrong with the obvious?

Distance(a,b) = length of shortest path, or infinity if there is none.

You probably should take directions into account, so a0 to a3 ist 1.

Answer (score 0):

The distance metric suggested by @Anony-Mousse is a good 
and natural one, but I question the use of dbscan. Using
the proposed

```
distance = length of shortest path, or infinity if there is none
```

Any two nodes that are directly linked would be at distance 1. 
If you used dbscan with epsilon < 1, all points would be noise
points. So you will want epsilon > 1. From your example, it looks 
like if there is even one point at distance 1,  you want them in 
the same component so 
it looks like you want minNumPts = 2.  This will give the 
result that it two points are connected by a path of any length
they would be in the same cluster. It looks to me like what 
you are after has nothing to do with density and clustering, 
rather, I think that what you want is connected components. 
If two nodes are connected by a path of any length, they are 
in the same component. Finding this via dbscan or some other clustering 
method may be possible, but that is probably the 
wrong way to think about this. You have a graph and a graph 
theoretic problem. You should probably use methods from graph 
theory.

I will illustrate using R and igraph. There are other tools
if you don't care for these.

Most of the work is simply setting up your problem.

```
library(igraph)

to   = c("a1", "a2", "a3", "a0", "b1", "b2", "b3", "b0")
from = c("a0", "a1", "a2", "a3", "b0", "b1", "b2", "b3")
EL   =  data.frame(from, to)

Vert = c("a0", "a1", "a2", "a3", "b0", "b1", "b2", "b3", "c0", "d0")
Vdf  = data.frame(Vert)

g = graph_from_data_frame(d = EL, vertices=Vdf)
LO = matrix(c(1.2,1,1,1.2, 2.2,2,2,2.2, 0, 3, 4,3,2,1,4,3,2,1,4,4), 
    ncol=2)
plot(g, layout=LO)
```

[image: Plot 1]

Now we can use a one-liner to get everything that we need 
about the components.

```
Comp = components(g, mode="weak")
Comp
$membership
a0 a1 a2 a3 b0 b1 b2 b3 c0 d0 
 1  1  1  1  2  2  2  2  3  4 
$csize
[1] 4 4 1 1
$no
[1] 4
```

This is telling us component membership of the nodes, 
the number of nodes per component and the number of 
components. Since you wanted to call the single node
components "noise" in the style of dbscan, you can 
see that components 3 and 4 have one node each.
They are the noise. The others are "real" components.
To show how to use this and to come to closure with a
pretty picture, I will plot the graph coloring the 
components and use light gray for the "noise".

```
ColorMap = rainbow(Comp$no)
ColorMap[Comp$csize == 1] = "lightgray"
plot(g, layout=LO, vertex.color=ColorMap[Comp$membership])
```

[image: Plot 2]

I encourage you to think about your graph problem as a graph.